# Why does LaTeX automatically insert unwanted spaces after a float page generated by \clearpage command?

Tags: spacing, floats, line-spacing, clearpage

I have a paper with three large floats that go to the end of the document when compiling the source code, their position vary depending on how I update the content, but they even go to the middle of references list sometimes.

[image]

Hence, I use `\afterpage{\clearpage}` to force the floats to go in a reasonable position. However, after placement of such command, some empty spaces appear after the float page. I used `\vspace{-<some number>\baselineskip}` to insert negative spaces. However, this is not good for two reasons:

1. With many changes in the document, the empty spaces change. Thus, the negative space can be either not enough or it may cause overprinting of contents.
2. The references are generated automatically by using `\bibliography{*.bib}`, hence, I would not be able to remove the space between references title and references list.

I am using `IEEEtran` document class

Here is how I force a float page while filling the current page (this works well for the page before the floats page)

[image]

Then this is my float page
[image]

After the float page
[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[svgnames, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{ \arraybackslash \Centering } X }
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand{\stackanchormath}[3][\stackgapSdefaultl]{
    \stackanchor[#1]{$#2$}{$#3$}
}

\newlength{\stackgapSdefaultl}
\setlength{\stackgapSdefaultl}{1.06mm}
\setstackgap{S}{\stackgapSdefaultl}



\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{afterpage}


\usepackage{blindtext}



\begin{document}


\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure*}

\begin{table*}[htb]

    \noindent
    \hspace*{\fill}
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}

        % Table options

        % Caption
        \caption{Top five weak combinations of PoIs at different voltage levels identified using the exhaustive search method}
        \label{table:ex_screen_result}

        % Center the table
        \centering

        \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{c ||C C C C C |C}

            \toprule

            & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\adjustbox{rotate=90, valign=c}{
                    \Shortunderstack{{Reference} {PoI}}
                } \hspace{\fill} \bfseries Combinations of PoIs \hspace{\fill} } &
            \adjustbox{rotate=90}{
                \Shortunderstack{{Min} {SDSCR}}
                                }
            \\
            \Xhline{0.25mm}

            \multirow{5}{0.3cm}{\adjustbox{rotate=90, valign=c, center}{$69$ KV}} & \bfseries 80 & \bfseries 84  & \bfseries 76 & \bfseries 81 & \bfseries 78 & \bfseries 1.77
            \\

            & 52 & 35 & 86 & 70 & 22 & 1.79
            \\

            & 40 & 45  & 80 & 90 & 10 & 1.80
            \\

            & 14 & 11  & 50 & 30 & 20 & 1.83
            \\

            & 18 & 88  & 32 & 02 & 01 & 1.85
            \\
            \Xhline{0.25mm}
            \addlinespace
            \Xhline{0.25mm}

            \multirow{5}{0.3cm}{\adjustbox{rotate=90, valign=c, center}{$34.5$ KV}} & \bfseries 1008 & \bfseries 926  & \bfseries 925 & \bfseries 885 & \bfseries 884 & \bfseries 2.65
            \\

            & 56 & 900  & 200 & 800 & 400 & 2.68
            \\

            & 450 & 500  & 400 & 300 & 250 & 2.76
            \\

            & 750 & 30  & 100 & 20 & 10 & 30
            \\

            & 40 & 80  & 30 & 180 & 120 & 3.06
            \\
            \Xhline{0.25mm}
            \addlinespace
            \Xhline{0.25mm}


            \multirow{5}{0.3cm}{\adjustbox{rotate=90, valign=c, center}{$13.8$ KV}} & \bfseries 969 & \bfseries 998 & \bfseries 1001 & \bfseries 1003 & \bfseries 1000 & \bfseries 1.20
            \\

            & 60 & 20 & 2000 & 1500 & 200 & 1.22
            \\

            & 40 & 30 & 450 & 50 & 30 & 1.42
            \\

            & 95 & 550 & 1400 & 14 & 1700 & 1.60
            \\

            & 200 & 900 & 1017 & 1222 & 3333 & 1.82
            \\
            \Xhline{0.25mm}
            \addlinespace
            \Xhline{0.25mm}

            \multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries \color{DeepSkyBlue2} Time Consumed} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries \color{DeepSkyBlue2} 8 hours}

            \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{\fill}
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}

        % Table options

        % Caption
        \caption{Top five weak combinations of PoIs at different voltage levels identified using the exhaustive search method}
        \label{table:ex_screen_result}

        % Center the table
        \centering

        \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{c ||C C C C C |C}

            \toprule

            & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\adjustbox{rotate=90, valign=c}{
                    \Shortunderstack{{Reference} {PoI}}
                } \hspace{\fill} \bfseries Combinations of PoIs \hspace{\fill} } &
            \adjustbox{rotate=90}{
                \Shortunderstack{{Min} {SDSCR}}
                                }
            \\
            \Xhline{0.25mm}

            \multirow{5}{0.3cm}{\adjustbox{rotate=90, valign=c, center}{$69$ KV}} & \bfseries 80 & \bfseries 84  & \bfseries 76 & \bfseries 81 & \bfseries 78 & \bfseries 1.77
            \\

            & 52 & 35 & 86 & 70 & 22 & 1.79
            \\

            & 40 & 45  & 80 & 90 & 10 & 1.80
            \\

            & 14 & 11  & 50 & 30 & 20 & 1.83
            \\

            & 18 & 88  & 32 & 02 & 01 & 1.85
            \\
            \Xhline{0.25mm}
            \addlinespace
            \Xhline{0.25mm}

            \multirow{5}{0.3cm}{\adjustbox{rotate=90, valign=c, center}{$34.5$ KV}} & \bfseries 1008 & \bfseries 926  & \bfseries 925 & \bfseries 885 & \bfseries 884 & \bfseries 2.65
            \\

            & 56 & 900  & 200 & 800 & 400 & 2.68
            \\

            & 450 & 500  & 400 & 300 & 250 & 2.76
            \\

            & 750 & 30  & 100 & 20 & 10 & 30
            \\

            & 40 & 80  & 30 & 180 & 120 & 3.06
            \\
            \Xhline{0.25mm}
            \addlinespace
            \Xhline{0.25mm}


            \multirow{5}{0.3cm}{\adjustbox{rotate=90, valign=c, center}{$13.8$ KV}} & \bfseries 969 & \bfseries 998 & \bfseries 1001 & \bfseries 1003 & \bfseries 1000 & \bfseries 1.20
            \\

            & 60 & 20 & 2000 & 1500 & 200 & 1.22
            \\

            & 40 & 30 & 450 & 50 & 30 & 1.42
            \\

            & 95 & 550 & 1400 & 14 & 1700 & 1.60
            \\

            & 200 & 900 & 1017 & 1222 & 3333 & 1.82
            \\
            \Xhline{0.25mm}
            \addlinespace
            \Xhline{0.25mm}

            \multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries \color{DeepSkyBlue2} Time Consumed} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries \color{DeepSkyBlue2} 8 hours}

            \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{\fill}

\end{table*}

\afterpage{\clearpage}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext


\section{Conclusions}
\blindtext


\section{Conclusions}
\blindtext


\section{Conclusions}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As always on this site please post a full minimal example that others can try. You can replace your images with `\rule{width}{height}`. As it sits now we have no way of saying anytihng as we don't know your document class, preamble etc

Comment: I wouldn't use \afterpage but the placeins package and \FloatBarrier.

Comment: @daleif I am trying to reproduce similar results

Comment: I wouldn't use `\afterpage` in a production document except as a really last resort (and I wrote it) the question you should be asking (and we can not answer from the posted information) is why are your floats going to the end of the document.

Comment: You should not need to use `\clearpage` or `\afterpage{\clearpage}` if you have accumulated enough floats to fill a float page I would expect latex to make a float page automatically, if that does not happen, there is something possibly wrong with the settings you have.

Comment: with respect to your final comment about inability to make a MWE it is always possible, just start from a copy of your document, delete anything you can delete while still showing the problem then replace every paragraph of  text by `x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x`  (with the right number of lines), and replace every image by `\rule{3cm}{4cm}` (using the right size for the image) latex will make the same float position decisions so the resulting example will show the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your comments. I just posted an MWE. `\afterpage` was the only solution. I had two tables that must be close together (hence I put their tabulars inside the same `table` environment), and one large figure. I tried to move floats codes around and change placement preferences, but nothing works well. `\afterpage{\clearpage}` placed the floats in a reasonable position albeit not really what I want.

Comment: I do not see any unexpected space in the output of the MWE?

Comment: Last page. The conclusions sections have too much of white and almost equal spaces between them, just as if `\vspace{\fill}` had been inserted multiple times there

Comment: I do not see that when I run your example. also the only reason that the table is not on a float page and so you have to force it on to a float page with `\clearpage` is that you have explicitly prevented it from being placed on a float page by `\begin{table*}[htb]`  which is the same as `\begin{table*}[t]` as 2-col floats can not use `h` or `b`.  Why do you prevent `p` here??????

Comment: Please use reasonably sized images next time! You don't need 5000x8000 images just to demonstrate extra spacing between paragraphs

Comment: Note that afterpage is explicitly not supported in two column documents (see `texdoc afterpage` page 1) so it is not expected to work here at all.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason that you need `\clearpage` to force the floats on to a float page is that the default positioning has been over-ridden `\begin{table*}[htb]` which is the same as `\begin{table*}[t]` as 2-col floats can not use h or b, does nothing other than prevent the table being placed on float pages other than the forced float pages from `\clearpage`.  If you remove this option and remove the `\afterpage{\clearpage}` you get reasonable positioning:

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[svgnames, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{ \arraybackslash \Centering } X }
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand{\stackanchormath}[3][\stackgapSdefaultl]{
    \stackanchor[#1]{$#2$}{$#3$}
}

\newlength{\stackgapSdefaultl}
\setlength{\stackgapSdefaultl}{1.06mm}
\setstackgap{S}{\stackgapSdefaultl}



\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{afterpage}


\usepackage{blindtext}



\begin{document}


\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure*}

\begin{table*}

    \noindent
    \hspace*{\fill}
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}

        % Table options

        % Caption
        \caption{Top five weak combinations of PoIs at different voltage levels identified using the exhaustive search method}
        \label{table:ex_screen_result}

        % Center the table
        \centering

        \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{c ||C C C C C |C}

            \toprule

            & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\adjustbox{rotate=90, valign=c}{
                    \Shortunderstack{{Reference} {PoI}}
                } \hspace{\fill} \bfseries Combinations of PoIs \hspace{\fill} } &
            \adjustbox{rotate=90}{
                \Shortunderstack{{Min} {SDSCR}}
                                }
            \\
            \Xhline{0.25mm}

            \multirow{5}{0.3cm}{\adjustbox{rotate=90, valign=c, center}{$69$ KV}} & \bfseries 80 & \bfseries 84  & \bfseries 76 & \bfseries 81 & \bfseries 78 & \bfseries 1.77
            \\

            & 52 & 35 & 86 & 70 & 22 & 1.79
            \\

            & 40 & 45  & 80 & 90 & 10 & 1.80
            \\

            & 14 & 11  & 50 & 30 & 20 & 1.83
            \\

            & 18 & 88  & 32 & 02 & 01 & 1.85
            \\
            \Xhline{0.25mm}
            \addlinespace
            \Xhline{0.25mm}

            \multirow{5}{0.3cm}{\adjustbox{rotate=90, valign=c, center}{$34.5$ KV}} & \bfseries 1008 & \bfseries 926  & \bfseries 925 & \bfseries 885 & \bfseries 884 & \bfseries 2.65
            \\

            & 56 & 900  & 200 & 800 & 400 & 2.68
            \\

            & 450 & 500  & 400 & 300 & 250 & 2.76
            \\

            & 750 & 30  & 100 & 20 & 10 & 30
            \\

            & 40 & 80  & 30 & 180 & 120 & 3.06
            \\
            \Xhline{0.25mm}
            \addlinespace
            \Xhline{0.25mm}


            \multirow{5}{0.3cm}{\adjustbox{rotate=90, valign=c, center}{$13.8$ KV}} & \bfseries 969 & \bfseries 998 & \bfseries 1001 & \bfseries 1003 & \bfseries 1000 & \bfseries 1.20
            \\

            & 60 & 20 & 2000 & 1500 & 200 & 1.22
            \\

            & 40 & 30 & 450 & 50 & 30 & 1.42
            \\

            & 95 & 550 & 1400 & 14 & 1700 & 1.60
            \\

            & 200 & 900 & 1017 & 1222 & 3333 & 1.82
            \\
            \Xhline{0.25mm}
            \addlinespace
            \Xhline{0.25mm}

            \multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries \color{DeepSkyBlue2} Time Consumed} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries \color{DeepSkyBlue2} 8 hours}

            \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{\fill}
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}

        % Table options

        % Caption
        \caption{Top five weak combinations of PoIs at different voltage levels identified using the exhaustive search method}
        \label{table:ex_screen_result}

        % Center the table
        \centering

        \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{c ||C C C C C |C}

            \toprule

            & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\adjustbox{rotate=90, valign=c}{
                    \Shortunderstack{{Reference} {PoI}}
                } \hspace{\fill} \bfseries Combinations of PoIs \hspace{\fill} } &
            \adjustbox{rotate=90}{
                \Shortunderstack{{Min} {SDSCR}}
                                }
            \\
            \Xhline{0.25mm}

            \multirow{5}{0.3cm}{\adjustbox{rotate=90, valign=c, center}{$69$ KV}} & \bfseries 80 & \bfseries 84  & \bfseries 76 & \bfseries 81 & \bfseries 78 & \bfseries 1.77
            \\

            & 52 & 35 & 86 & 70 & 22 & 1.79
            \\

            & 40 & 45  & 80 & 90 & 10 & 1.80
            \\

            & 14 & 11  & 50 & 30 & 20 & 1.83
            \\

            & 18 & 88  & 32 & 02 & 01 & 1.85
            \\
            \Xhline{0.25mm}
            \addlinespace
            \Xhline{0.25mm}

            \multirow{5}{0.3cm}{\adjustbox{rotate=90, valign=c, center}{$34.5$ KV}} & \bfseries 1008 & \bfseries 926  & \bfseries 925 & \bfseries 885 & \bfseries 884 & \bfseries 2.65
            \\

            & 56 & 900  & 200 & 800 & 400 & 2.68
            \\

            & 450 & 500  & 400 & 300 & 250 & 2.76
            \\

            & 750 & 30  & 100 & 20 & 10 & 30
            \\

            & 40 & 80  & 30 & 180 & 120 & 3.06
            \\
            \Xhline{0.25mm}
            \addlinespace
            \Xhline{0.25mm}


            \multirow{5}{0.3cm}{\adjustbox{rotate=90, valign=c, center}{$13.8$ KV}} & \bfseries 969 & \bfseries 998 & \bfseries 1001 & \bfseries 1003 & \bfseries 1000 & \bfseries 1.20
            \\

            & 60 & 20 & 2000 & 1500 & 200 & 1.22
            \\

            & 40 & 30 & 450 & 50 & 30 & 1.42
            \\

            & 95 & 550 & 1400 & 14 & 1700 & 1.60
            \\

            & 200 & 900 & 1017 & 1222 & 3333 & 1.82
            \\
            \Xhline{0.25mm}
            \addlinespace
            \Xhline{0.25mm}

            \multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries \color{DeepSkyBlue2} Time Consumed} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries \color{DeepSkyBlue2} 8 hours}

            \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{\fill}

\end{table*}



\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext


\section{Conclusions}
\blindtext


\section{Conclusions}
\blindtext


\section{Conclusions}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked with the MWE but not my original code. I added a picture showing where the tables go when I let them float as LaTeX wants. Sometime my document gets crowded with tables, figures, and equations that are very close to each other, and LaTeX pushes them to the end even when requesting `h` positioning or reducing the floats sizes.

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh using "h" as option makes it *harder* for latex to find a suitable place. Better use ! or change the float parameters. See e.g. https://texfaq.org/FAQ-floats

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just solved it by placing finding better placement of the tables and figures source codes. I still, however, would like to know why `\clearpage` inserts the empty spaces in the page that follows the float page. Is that a bug in LaTeX or `float` package?

@David Charlisle. I did not know that `t` and `b` placements are meaningless in two-column documents unless there is a float page. Thank you

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh using `[h]` on a single column float makes it almost certain the float goes to the end of the document, `h` and `b` are not "meaningless unless ther is a float page, they are always ignored, `h` has no possible meaning for a 2-col float and `b` is not supported by default although there are some packages that support that)

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh we can only answer the questions as asked, if your MWE does not show the problem you should change the MWE (It has no bad space even as posted in your question) but for your real document, first make sure that _every_ figure or table that has an optional argument includes `p` in the options. Doing anything else makes it impossible for latex to make float pages and will force most floats to the end of the document.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem with an IEEE journal template. I tried to replace the `\clearpage` by `%\vspace*{size}` but that was working only in one column. So I tried to switch the mode to add the space and found out that just this (without the space):

```
\onecolumn
\twocolumn
```

Is sufficient to create the new page (put it there instead of the `\clearpage` attempts).

What also kind of worked was encapsulating the problematic sections in `\vbox` and eventually positioning them to the possible blank space with `%\vspace*{-size}`.

Other solutions with positioning of the other objects, flushing and new page commands were not working at all for me.